# Azure Devops-release pipeline

Tags: azure, deployment, devops, release

Can we create release pipeline in azure devops using yaml?
(I know we can add stages in pipelines ,but i want to know if we can create pipeline in pipelines -> release by yaml not classic pipeline.)

Answer (score 0):

you can build and release in the same pipeline, we have a multi stage pipeline, the first stage builds the subsequent stages deploy to the different environments and run automated test
[image]

Alternatively you can separate it in to different yaml pipelines